# Nginx Cannot Bind Error

Tags: nginx, centos

Whenever I try to access my website, that is running Nginx, this error message is shown in the logs:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I have looked around, and mostly what people say to do is kill the nginx service and restart it, as well as any other services that are using the port, which may be the cause of the issue. When I run a netstat command, this is what is shown:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3997/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3997/nginx: master
```

Then, I kill the tasks with:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

I ran netstat again to make sure nothing was running, and nothing was. I then proceeded to restart nginx only to find that it still had this error. Here is my nginx configuration file:

```
server 
{
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com;
    root           /var/www/html;
    index          index.html;

    location ~* \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding the ipv6=on or something similar tag to the bottom listen port, but that did not affect anything. If anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your nginx.conf seems correct, so it's not about nginx.conf. I guess some process is restarted by some kind of watchdog. Check it with "lsof -Pni :80" before starting nginx next time

Comment: Turns out, it had nothing to do with nginx. It was actually because my port 80 wasn't open.